# How to get (Reference1; Reference2; see Reference3 for review)?

Tags: citing, natbib

I'm using `natbib` package (`\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}`) and I want something like:

> (Buhusi, 2009; see Bueti, 2011 for review)

If I do `\citep[see][for review]{Buhusi,Bueti}`, I can get,

> (see Buhusi, 2009; Bueti, 2011 for review)

but I want the see X for review only for the last reference. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
(\citealp{Buhusi}; \citealp[see][for review]{Bueti})
```

If you wanted to automate the insertion of parentheses around the two citations, you could type

```
\citetext{\citealp{Buhusi}; \citealp[see][for review]{Bueti}}
```

but it seems (to me at least) easier to just insert the parentheses manually.